# Interactive Windows Service?

Tags: python, windows, service, ctypes

I created a Windows Service in Python and tried to get the current window by
GetForegroundWindow() from ctypes.
To check if the PC is locked ( GetForegroundWindow() == when the PC is locked, works fine in a normal Python Skript)

Apparently the Service has to be a "Interactive Service" to recognize the current Window.

So the question is: Is there a way to start the Service as a Interactive Service ?

The Windows Service is structured like this (I deleted some parts of the code so the post isnt that long):

```
class Service(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "Service"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Service"


    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        # Create an event which we will use to wait on.
        # The "service stop" request will set this event.
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        # Tell ReportServiceStatus we are starting the stop process.
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, waitHint=10000)

        # And set stop event.
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def GetAcceptedControls(self):

        result = win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.GetAcceptedControls(self)
        result |= win32service.SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN
        return result

    def SvcOtherEx(self, control, event_type, data):

        if control == win32service.SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN:
            #_log('received a pre-shutdown notification')
            self.SvcStop()

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        user32 = ctypes.windll.User32
        #Do Something 

        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(str(user32.GetForegroundWindow()))

        # Wait until the Service is stopped
        win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, win32event.INFINITE)
```

Comment: Thomas Weller 's anwser worked fine on one PC on which I knew the username and password, but I have to run this on other PCs on which I dont know these, so i came up with a little "shitty" workaround. I wrote a little Python script which is checking if the PC is locked and writes the result to a txt which is read by the Windows Service. The script is in the startup folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to start the Service as a Interactive Service ?

I do not recommend to do so.

You should create a process which runs in the context of the user's desktop. See [CreateProcessAsUser()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms682429). That process can then have a GUI and communicate with your service.

I, against all advice, you still want to create an interactive service, read [MSDN on Interactive Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/Services/interactive-services). Be aware that in most cases, this exposes the PC to security risk.

Comment: hi, thank you for your fast anwser. I see the problem you mentioned and think the solution to create a new process as user seems very good.But there is one problem. I have to run the Service on many different Computers on which I dont always know the users and the users are forced to change their passwords regularly. Is there a way to create the token out of the current logged in user ?